# How do two hosts connected to the same WI-FI communicate?

Tags: wireless-networking, dd-wrt

I have the following setup of two RPIs connected to a wireless router flashed with DD-WRT. 
If I ping the RPIs from the router I get around 4ms of delay. If I ping one RPI from the other i get around 8ms of delay. To me, this makes sense: RPI1->access point, access point->RPI2 (4 + 4 = 8)

[image]

However, if I add additional delay to br0, or eth1 (the wireless card) using netem:

tc qdisc add dev eth1 root netem delay 100ms.

I obtain the following scenario:

[image]

How is this possible?

Comment: Your chart clearly shows: direct connection between 2 rpis (in the same lan), ddwrt doesn't route anything.

Comment: @IporSircer, but in wireless doesn't the communication go sender->access-point -> receiver? The information has to go by the router.

Comment: You don't mention what specifically seems out of the ordinary to you, so it's hard to answer your question. What do you find surprising or in need of explanation?

Comment: Possibly the packet never leaves eth1 when it is forwarded to the other WLAN client, so the delay doesn't apply. OTOH, when the destination is the router itself, the delay *does* apply.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I find it strange that in the second scenario the delay between the two hosts is not ~ 200 ms. Given that the delay between one host and the access point is ~100 ms. In the first scenario the delay is 8ms between the hosts and 4 ms between each host and the access point (4 + 4 = 8 so, to me it makes sense).

Comment: @dirkt that is what puzzles me as well... I was expecting 200ms of delay.

Comment: @TropE - As pointed out by David, the delay only exist, locally on the client.

Comment: @Ramhound When you say client, do you refer to the RPI? because the delay was added to the wireless ethernet card of the router.

Comment: Based on the command the delay was added to eth1 which would only be local on the client itself.

Comment: it is still not clear to what you refer at when you say client: the RPI or the router? How is it local? When i ping from the RPI to the router it gets the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the two RPi's communicate with each other, the access point does have to forward packets from one to the other. This is internal functionality of the access point function and has nothing to do with the fact that it presents a network interface to the operating system for packets sent and received locally.

You imposed a delay on the local network interface, not the internals of the access point function.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? How come it has nothing to do with the network interface? I mean isn't the wi-fi card in the router the one that is responsible for the wireless communication? In wireless the data always has to go sender->access point -> receiver. Are you saying that data doesn't pass through the wi-fi card of the access point in this scenario?

Comment: @TropE It doesn't pass through the network interface that the wireless hardware presents to the operating system. It is an internal function of the access point. You can think of it as having two things: One, a wireless radio that acts as an access point. Two, a local network interface that connects the local machine to that radio network. For traffic that goes from one client to another, only the first thing is used. You applied a delay to the second thing.

Comment: And how does the wireless radio knows to which of its clients to forward the messages if it doesn't interact with the network interface?

Comment: @TropE The access point part has the table of clients specifically so that it knows how to forward packets. The network interface only handles local traffic. (Wired devices typically work precisely the same way. A SoHo router might have a 4 port switch that provides its four LAN ports and that switch also presents a network interface for local packets. The CPU never sees packets that are switched between the LAN ports because that's part of the switch part, not the network interface part that the CPU uses to talk to devices on the LAN.)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  Do you know if there is a possibility to force the packets to be routed through the ethernet card so that they are delayed? My purpose is to shape the traffic between the two RPI by manipulating the router.

Comment: @TropE Sure, just use the router as a router, not as an access point. Assign the two RPi's IP addresses inside different subnets and let the device route between the two.

Comment: Would that mean that if you have for example 10-20 RPIs all of them would need to be in a different subnet? Is this feasible to implement on personal-use WI-FI router? I am using a Netgear R7000 for this project.

Comment: @TropE Yes, they'd each need to be in their own subnet. It's doable for 10-20, I think, though I've never tried.